# Issue downloading one Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, mvn-repo

I get this error when running `mvn clean install`:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Hian-Persistence-Direct: Could not resolve dependencies for project ue.hian:Hian-Persistence-Direct:jar:3.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.ibatis:ibatis2:jar:2.3.0.677: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.ibatis:ibatis2:jar:2.3.0.677: Could not transfer artifact com.ibatis:ibatis2:pom:2.3.0.677 from/to maven-public (https://binaries.me.com/artifactory/public-maven): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
> [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :Hian-Persistence-Direct

I'm running this in the command line. Is it possible that I don't have maven configured correctly? Failing that, how do I get the full path to the problem dependency? I'd like to check if I can reach it through the browser.

Comment: "ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized" Means you are accessing repository which required authorization. You need to present valid credientials.

Comment: I can access `https://binaries.me.com/artifactory/public-maven` through my browser and am able to see other packages so through this might have been a red herring. Also, my SA told me I have read only access by default so thought that meant to all packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an incorrect password to the artifact in my settings.xml